# Comment explaining downvote keeps on being deleted - why?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

A [poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-from-range#comment37127581_18481330) gets asked, I downvote and leave a comment explaining the down-vote along the lines of *"-1 as this has been asked many times before and you haven't tried anything"*. The comment receives several upvotes as the question quickly gathers 4 downvotes

Some time later, I revisit this question when posting to [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223544/what-drives-me-away-from-here#comment740417_223544) thread. The comment is gone, so I add it back in with similar words

Today I look again, and the comment is gone a second time.

What gives?

The comment explains a downvote to a poor question, and it is certainly not:

- not constructive
- obsolete
- too chatty
- other

And given this has been written as a plain factual statement, it is drawing a very long bow for a moderator to twice have agreed with someone - I can guess who - that is is "rude or offensive".

People ofte gripe as to why they have been downvoted, I would have thought given a reason should be encouraged rather than discouraged.

Any ideas/comments as to why would this have been removed? I promise not to flag any comments I don't like for removal .........

Comment: The point was made, I guess the OP must have seen it (and he hasn't been back since January) ... why does it need to hang around?

Comment: .. as comment is of course now gone again, I will accept this and move on.

Comment: Might have been more constructive to post a link to the Intro pages.

Comment: related: [Is it OK to say +1 with a reason why you're upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270356/is-it-ok-to-say-1-with-a-reason-why-youre-upvoting)

Comment: To you it might appear as a "plain factual statement" but to a new user I'm fairly certain it will be interpreted as distinctly unfriendly, curt, and lacking in any real guidance. Tone matters. It is difficult for some people to ask for help, and very discouraging to be faced with this kind of coldness when they do. So rather than saying "this has been asked before" why not say "you can find the help you need in this <link-to-duplicate>, and please be aware in future that when you type a question the right hand side of your brower will suggest answers that you *should* read before you post."

Comment: @user6170930 your points are certainly fair.  I did struggle with adopting the SO depersonalised tone when I first joined and perhaps at times now I am too crisp, particularly on poor questions. Also not sure it is worth explaining down votes regardless of how well it is done - some people over react.

Comment: I agree that its a fine line, and a difficult one to walk when trying to get through to a moron. I find it best to not engage at all if my patience is wearing thin. Someone else will always pick up the slack.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your comment is not constructive.

There's no need to add a comment that simply restates what's on the down-vote tooltip, especially one that starts "-1".

If you want to leave a comment, at least make it more useful to poster.

*(As an aside comments that start +1 aren't constructive either and tend to get removed too.)*

Comment: was tempted to add +1 .... but thought the better of it. Point taken though. In future won't bother with comments along these lines.

Comment: "constructive" in this sense would be *to the user who wrote the post* - I'd argue any explanation for a downvote, as long as it hasn't already been said, is going to vastly improve the usability of the site for new/ignorant members.  Sure the -1 is useless to start it with, but poor formatting doesn't make it unconstructive.

Comment: This might be easy to understand by some, however the down-vote tooltip says "This answer is not useful" and the OP's comment said "this has been asked many times before" - these 2 phrases are not identical and hence I would argue that the comment is indeed constructive (especially considering the number of non-English-1st-language users on our site)

Comment: I once had the scenario that the OP asked why his code didn’t work which had `++1` in a loop instead of `++i`. I commented something like “`++1` is not going to work, use `++i` instead.” and SO recognized that as an “upvote comment” which it wasn’t and it definitely was constructive.

Comment: @Xufox - You've found what's probably the only case where you'd want to start a comment with `+1` :)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier That's true, but a at least a link to one of those "similar questions" would help the user out and be a bit more constructive than just stating a fact. "This question has been asked many times before, maybe you can find your answer [here], [here] or [here]". It's like simply saying "use the search function" - true, but still not that helpfull.

Comment: @Katai I agree that would make it even more constructive

Comment: "If you want to leave a comment, at least make it more useful to poster."  Even if doing that, [it'll still be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329888/why-did-this-comment-disappear).

Answer (score 4):

The comment is not constructive, because it presents a problem without a solution.  If you reword it so that it has exactly the same meaning:

> This question gets asked a lot.  Use the search function and try out some of the existing answers.  If they don't help you, clearly explain what you tried and how your situation differs so that previously given advice isn't helping.

then it should be allowed to stay.