# I can't get out of my question ban because no one is voting for my new questions

Tags: support, asking-questions, voting, deleted-questions, post-ban

I've been in a question ban for about 4 years, and have had no luck getting out. I've been asking the occasional question in hopes of getting votes to get out, but so far, they haven't been getting any votes. As of writing this, [my latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071131/how-do-i-base-a-css-property-on-another-element) hasn't been getting any votes after stagnating at about 50 views.

On a side note, I have 3 deleted questions (although one of them gives a 404 error so that's probably no longer associated) that I had to ask a moderator for a link to to even see them. They can't be improved (and I'm being dead serious. I'll even include links/screenshots if you don't believe me. You can't polish a turd after all) and I don't even ask those kinds of questions any more.

Surely deleted questions should just disappear for good and stop counting against me to the point of not existing in the first place. Otherwise, what even is the point of deleting a question? Is it just so that users don't have to deal with the question being public **and at the same time** be hit with a question ban? Surely the right to be forgotten (or forgiven) could be useful here, especially if questions like those haven't been posted in **years**).

Comment: Rule one about votes: don't talk about them.

Comment: In that last question you say: *(yes I have tried to Google for an answer)*. It would help if you include what terms you used to search for and one or two links to posts you looked into but weren't useful and why.

Comment: And while you're presenting pseudo code that still means it does need to make sense. You got a comment that raised that point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071131/how-do-i-base-a-css-property-on-another-element#comment100668651_57071131) but is not addressed.

Comment: As I'm not familiar with CSS and its crazy features I did a naive [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+calc+parent+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A1&mixed=0). Any chance one of those 155 results achieves what you need where you then can extend on to explain which of your requirements are missing from thw answer you found? That gives potential answerers a working starting point.

Comment: *Surely the right to be forgotten (or forgiven) could be useful here, especially if questions like those haven't been posted in years).* I can relate.

Comment: "Otherwise, what even is the point of deleting a question?" If the question is truly unsalvageable, it keeps it from collecting even more downvotes. And if deleted questions didn't count against you there wouldn't be much point in having a question ban mechanic in the first place since it would be trivial to get out of.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery "And if deleted questions didn't count against you there wouldn't be much point in having a question ban mechanic in the first place since it would be trivial to get out of." What about the questions ceasing to count against me after a long time has passed?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Also, don't expect me to counter them with questions with upvotes, when no one is even going to vote (not even downvote, just not vote at all).

Comment: @rene I still need to know why people are downvoting my question. Downvotes with no comments attached can't help in improving the question.



Also, even if I improve my question, there would be no way of notifying the downvoter of the change, and if your post stops gaining views, the damage would already be done.


If only Stack Overflow allowed us to ping downvoters to remind them to explain themselves or recast their vote.

Comment: I would get so many pings, my inbox would overflow.

Comment: The down votes on a question mean: it is unclear, not well researched, not useful. Looking at this very meta question: not well researched could certainly count, for example because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370929/why-are-downvoted-questions-closed-without-giving-the-author-the-chance-to-respo) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258605/comment-explaining-downvote-keeps-on-being-deleted-why) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436)

Comment: I don't want this to become a blame game but the guidance on [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583) spend some words on fixing existing posts and contributing positively. Maybe we need to better define what we consider as contributing and fixing but [what is on your public record](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881189/fluorescentgreen5?tab=activity&sort=all) doesn't look like if you have done any of those. The onus is on you, not on the (down) voters.

Comment: @rene How does it look like im not positively contributing?

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 for example you have made hardly any edits. Nor did you vote much, nor did you flag much, nor do you have many suggested edits to improve posts from others, nor did you do any reviews. You did use your privilege to post on Meta where you point out to others that they should vote more. There seems to be  an imbalance, at least from my point of view.

Comment: @rene So I went and made a bunch of edits and votes to the questions I answered.

Comment: Awesome, assuming you voted on the merits of the posts, not because I told you so. Now keep that up for the next 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 Please try to retrospect. I would also like to point out the title. After going through your list of questions the rephrased title I can think of is "I can't get out of question ban because my questions don't compel people enough to vote upon them based on the tooltip that appears when they hover over the voting buttons."

Comment: see also: [Removing phrases like “I looked everywhere on the internet and I did not find anything”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283163/839601)

Comment: How much time did you really spend writing that question? Because it looks like 10 minutes, tops. Undoing a ban would involve a bit more effort. This particular question might have done well with some MDN references, or a short browser devtools/css property inspection *screencast*.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/38238142) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/28710228))

Comment: @SamuelLiew what should I do about them?

Comment: @mario How long should I spend writing a question? 1 hour?

Comment: @rene My voting was undone because it was "serial", eventhough I didn't upvote questions that were "bad".

Comment: @Rahul Take a look at the last line of my recent question: "I would like to know how to do this without using scripts and definite numbers (such as `100px`), as a lot of answers (yes I have tried to Google for an answer) I've seen include these."

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 in the current state you're in you haver 6 months. I would use those. Nowadays good questions takes days, not only for writing but also for researching as there is enough material to study.

Comment: Voting gets reversed if you cast many votes in a short period and/or on the same user. Don't do that. Voting also takes time. And time seems something you don't want to spend. That is a shame because that time investment is needed to get you anywhere on these sites, at least on SO.

Comment: @rene I have to dedicate 6 months just to get out of this ban? Do they really expect me to dedicate the better part of my life just to get out of this ban? Had SO considered the right to be forgotten (especially since the negative score deleted questions are really, really old), I wouldn't even be in this question ban.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 well, you should have dedicated that time before you got to this point but now that you reached this far, yes, dedicate at least that 6 months to get out of the ban. Your suggestion for "the right to be forgotten" requires no effort from your side which is exactly opposite what the ban is meant for.

Comment: @rene I'm still getting downvotes for my question I improved (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071131/how-do-i-base-a-css-property-on-another-element). Is there a damn flowchart for writing a good question that I'm missing?

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 yes, beyond the damned [help] there is the damned [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and there is the damned [Down voting reason guidance](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) and there is a whole damned [tag:FAQ] and if you're done with that you can even get meta-damned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites Plenty of guidance I would say ...

Comment: You're unlucky, really you are. Many of the more vocal users are disenchanted with SO as a whole and so they vent their frustrations on someone who hasn't followed the guidelines or isn't aware of the culture. Six months is a ridiculous long time to be banned, especially if the questions were posted years ago and are unsalvageable, and it's predictable that they will earn further downvotes if undeleted because downvoters want to emphasis a view-point. The entire comment section is really disappointing. There are some very useful links but mainly couched in thinly veiled sarcastic tones.

Comment: Take note of unspoken rule number one, mentioned earlier: never ever talk about downvotes in a *question*, in an answer that's fine but not in Q, once a question has received an upvoted answer, it gives the community permission to DV the Q even further and OPs cannot be delete when a scored answer has been submitted.  And never blame downvotes for a question ban.

Comment: @Mari-LouA true all that. Sarcastic I am.

Comment: @rene You have a wealth of experience and knowledge, as shown by your rep and by the links posted, just try and be a bit more sympathetic to someone who wants to improve their posts and just needs some help. Again, I understand the frustration, the same things have to be said again and again ad infinitum, but the real fault lies with the system, not with users asking their questions for the first time. BTW how many LQs are allowed to pass before a Q ban is automatically imposed?

Comment: @Mari-LouA you can pass many LQ's as long as you bring in enough positive scoring ones. That doesn't seem the case for this [user profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions?negdel=2&closedel=2&deleted=2&UserId=3881189). They would need to have their lowest scoring questions disassociated from their profile to have a chance of digging themselves out. It is an option that would require using the Contact Us form at the bottom of the page and then hope SE staff is merciful, again.

Comment: You probably need to read the following post and keep in mind all the suggestions and tips mentioned. [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture).

Comment: @Mari-LouA seeing how unnecessarily hard it is to get out of the ban, is there anyone out there who has a PhD in getting out of a question ban (i.e. dedicated their career to learning the art)? Also, have there been any data annalists who found out the approximate threshold for determining bans?

Answer (score 4):

Question bans are deliberately hard to get and even harder to escape. You need to polish up every question you have as much as possible. If that doesn't work, try answering. But after asking enough bad questions to trigger the ban, it will be extremely difficult for you to get unbanned.

Comment: I have 3 bad (deleted) questions, and only 1 with a negative score. Question bans are by no means, hard to get. Also, which questions of mine need polishing up?

Comment: Undelete the questions. They may count against you. Also, I say question bans are hard to get because you are given so many warnings and chances before the ban comes

Comment: I have also gotten into warning around 5 months ago(my last question was that time ago ;) and I have one question with -1 and another with -2(it was -1 when I had warning and after 2 months got another down vote) but now my warning has gone, how's that possible?

Comment: @AlecAlameddine 1 question now gives a 404 error, the other is a duplicate (deleted by community) and I no longer remember enough about the last question to improve it (it's also closed by other people).

Comment: Do you have link to that one question that is a 404 for you @FluorescentGreen5 ?  It is hardly ever stuff gets hard deleted.

Comment: @rene Yes, but it's a question about what kind of specs I should get for a gaming laptop, which I asked when I was new: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978977/what-specs-should-i-upgrade-on-my-laptop-if-i-were-to-use-it-to-play-games

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 okay, that question got disassociated from your user profile so that is no longer one you need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting question will not help, instead, try to improve the question by adding more specific and relevant details. By improving question it will be on the top for the active tab of question tag where the others can see your updated question which is more to the point and with appropriate details. By doing this there may be a chance of upvote to question

Comment: I've already covered that the questions can't be improved.

Comment: Will editing a question attract attention? Because if no one is going to see your edit, what even is the point of improving the question?

Comment: There are so many people who maintains the tag watch to see the updates, So there is some chance of getting attention to questions which has improved contain which might result in upvote